# Relationship between content types

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have two content types: *Region* and *City*. *Region* nodes include *City* nodes; every *City* node is related to some *Region* node.

How I can create a relationship for this situation? When I create a *Region* node and refer a *City* node in a field, all *City* nodes have its *Region* referencing field set to this *Region* node and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) to achieve this.

Follow these steps:

1. Create two content types: **Region** and **City**.
2. Insert entity reference field: `Cities` in **Region** and `Region` in **City**.
3. Now enable [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) and update its configuration by going on your site: Configuration >> System >> Corresponding entity references.
4. Check this configuration: **Correspond Region on node(s) of type city with Cities on node(s) of type region.**
   [image]
5. Now in next tab **Updating existing entities** of entity type: **node**.
   [image]